# Mudar CSS pela classe no JavaScript, é possível?

Tags: javascript, classes

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer alterações no CSS de uma classe pelo JavaScript. Conseguimos pegar as divs pelo id com o comando `document.getElementById("nomedaiddadiv");`. Tem algum comando que faça o mesmo, porém com as classes das *divs*?

Obrigado.

Comment: A sua pergunta é ambígua. A resposta do Valdeir Psr parte de uma premissa, e a do Guilherme Nascimento, de outra. Qual das duas coisas você queria saber? Como selecionar elementos com base numa classe, ou como alterar os estilos definidos numa classe? Se for alterar os estilos, é como o Valdeir explicou. Mas é raro realmente precisar disso. Geralmente é mais simples acrescentar e remover classes dos elementos.

Answer (score 2):

> Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer alterações no CSS de uma classe pelo JavaScript.

Sim, é possível alterar classes do CSS através do JavaScript, para isso você só precisa utilizar `document.styleSheets[indice].cssRules`, esse código irá listar todos as classes de um determinado `<style>` ou `<link>`.

Esse código te dará acesso a API [CSSRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule), com isso você poderá alterar sua classe CSS através do JavaScript.

**Exemplo:**

```js
const classeQueDesejoAlterar = ".italic";

/* Percorre todas as regras CSS do primeiro Stylesheet da página */
let cssRuleList = [...document.styleSheets[0].cssRules].filter( rule => rule.selectorText == classeQueDesejoAlterar)

/* Percorre todas as regras capturadas e aplica o CSS */
for (let cssRule of cssRuleList) {
  cssRule.style.setProperty("background", "red")
}
```

```css
h1 {font-size: 50%}

.italic {font-style:italic}
```

```html
<h1>StackOverflow</h1>
<p class="italic">Teste</p>
```

Claro que esse código funciona bem quando você sabe a ordem dos *CSS*, mas caso você não saiba, você pode cria ruma função para listar todos os CSS da página, por exemplo:

```js
const classeQueDesejoAlterar = ".italic";

/* Lista e percorre todos os Stylesheet da página */
for (let stylesheet of document.styleSheets) {

  /* Lista e filtra a regra do CSS */
  let cssRuleList = [...document.styleSheets[0].cssRules].filter(rule => rule.selectorText == classeQueDesejoAlterar)

  /* Percorre todas as regras encontradas e aplica o CSS. */
  for (let cssRule of cssRuleList) {
    cssRule.style.setProperty("background", "red")
  }
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 50%
}

.italic {
  font-style: italic
}
```

```html
<h1>StackOverflow</h1>
<p class="italic">Teste</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo:
Por JavaScript "nativo":

```
var m = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); c = m.style;
c.color = "#c00";
c.backgroundColor = "#eee";
c.width = "200px";
c.height = "100px";
c.borderColor = "#f00";
```

Por jQuery:

```
 $("div").css({
    color: "#c00",
    backgroundColor: "#eee",
    width: "200px",
    height: "100px",
    borderColor: "#f00"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Baseado no que disse:

> Conseguimos pegar as divs pelo id com o comando `document.getElementById("nomedaiddadiv");`. Tem algum comando que faça o mesmo, porém com as classes das divs?

Você quer "pegar" os elementos de maneira semelhante como já faz com ids

Para pegar pela classe ou pelo ID ou por qualquer seletor compativel com CSS use as funções:

- `document.querySelector`
- `document.querySelectorAll`

O uso destas duas funções será muito mais pratico que usar `document.getElementById` e `document.getElementsByTagName`, pois o seletor irá lhe permitir ser bem mais pratico.

O `querySelector` pega somente o primeiro elemento que for encontrado, por exemplo:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".foo").textContent);
console.log(document.querySelector(".bar").textContent);
console.log(document.querySelector(".baz").textContent);
```

```html
<div class="foo bar baz">
Elemento 1
</div>

<div class="foo bar baz">
Elemento 2
</div>
```

O `querySelectorAll` pega todos elementos que for encontrado, então será necessário usar um `for` (ou `forEach`, no entanto este somente em navegadores modernos):

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".foo");
 
for (var i = 0, j = els.length; i < j; i++) {
    console.log(els[i].textContent);
}
```

```html
<div class="foo bar baz">
Elemento 1
</div>

<div class="foo bar baz">
Elemento 2
</div>
```

Então para alterar o CSS você pode criar uma classe especifica e adicionar usando `.classList.add`, por exemplo:

```js
document.querySelector(".adicionar").onclick = function () {
    document.querySelector(".foo").classList.add("novoestilo");
};
```

```css
.novoestilo {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo bar baz">
Elemento 1
</div>
<button class="adicionar">Adicionar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem, isso ajuda!

```js
var divId = document.getElementById('div1');
var divClass = document.getElementsByClassName('div-class');
var divElement = document.getElementsByTagName('div');



console.log('Por Id: ', divId);
console.log('Por Class: ', divClass);
console.log('Por Elemento: ', divElement);
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="div-class">1</div>
<div id="div2" class="div-class">2</div>
<div id="div3" class="div-class">3</div>
<div id="div4" class="div-class">4</div>
```

Observação: Caso queira obter um elemento específico nos casos onde mais que um elemento for encontrado, trate como um array, exemplo: `divElement[0]`