# Alterar uma classe CSS pelo JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho essa classe no meu CSS:

```
.botao-localizacao{
    display: block;
}
```

Ela não existe no meu html, somente no CSS.

Logo, minha dúvida é: como faço para alterar ela no meu javascript/jquery?

EX:

```
.botao-localizacao{
    display: none;
}
```

Quero fazer isso pq to inserindo html através do append, ele contém essa classe mas não consigo acessa-lá.

Ou teria uma maneira de eu acessar essa classe mais facilmente? Sei que pra isso preciso usar o `$(document).on`, só que não gostaria de adicionar nenhum evento para ela, só buscar essa classe.

Aqui é onde insiro o HTML:

```
for(var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {
    $(".listagem-cartoes").append(
        `<div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;">
            <div class="cartoes">
                <div class="item-total">
                    <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3" style="width: 50%;">
                        <div class="card-panel grey lighten-5 z-depth-1">
                            <div class="row valign-wrapper foto" id = ${id}>
                                <div class="col s3 lista-cartoneira editar-cartao" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                                    <img src="${results.rows.item(i).img2 + '?time=' + d.getTime()}" alt="" class="circle responsive-img foto" id=${id}> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col s9 lista-cartoneira">
                                    <h1>${nomeEmpresa}</h1>
                                    <h2>${nome}</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3" style="width: 50%; float: right; margin-top: -136px;">
                    <div class="card-panel grey lighten-5 z-depth-1">
                        <div class="row valign-wrapper botoes">
                            <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3" style="background-color: #00b0ff;">
                                <i class="material-icons telefone" id=${id}>phone</i>
                             </div>
                             <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3" style="background-color: #ffb74d;">
                                 <i class="material-icons email" id=${id}>email</i>
                             </div>
                             <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3 botao-localizacao" style="background-color: #757575;">
                                 <i class="material-icons localizacao" id=${id}>place</i>
                             </div>
                             <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3" style="background-color: #00BFA5;">
                                 <i class="material-icons compartilhar" id=${id}>open_in_new</i>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div> 
             </div>
         </div>`
     );
}
```

Observem ali a classe .botao-localização

```
<div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3 botao-localizacao" style="background-color: #757575;">
    <i class="material-icons localizacao" id=${id}>place</i>
</div>
```

Em algum desses elementos, eu vou precisar remover essa classe/esconder.  Ou seja, não vai mais existir todo esse html que nada mais é que um botão. Logo, queria fazer algo como: `$(.botao-localizacao > id).css('display', 'none') ou $('.botao-localizacao > id').hide();`

```
<div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s3 botao-localizacao" style="background-color: #757575;">
    <i class="material-icons localizacao" id=${id}>place</i>
</div>
```

Comment: Se a classe está interferindo no seu elemento, não seria mais fácil removê-la do elemento do que tentar editar com JS a classe no CSS, correndo o risco de gerar inúmeros efeitos colaterais?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss na verdade eu insiro vários com o mesmo HTML, logo só alguns desses elementos terão essa classe, então eu teria que fazer algo como $(".botao-localizacao > id") para alterar somente o que precisa ser alterado.

Comment: Você pode postar alguma parte do seu código, o que você já fez?

Comment: Para buscar essa classe com **jQuery** você pode utilizar `$('.botao-localizacao')`, para adicionar a classe a um elemento `$(meuElemento).addClass('botao-localizacao');`

Comment: Isso está parecendo um Problema XY, em que você precisa de ajuda para fazer algo que não é a solução para o problema. Talvez será interessante você [edit] a pergunta e criar um [mcve] que nos mostre o problema real, para então te ajudarmos a decidir qual é a melhor solução.

Comment: @AlvaroAlves editei a pergunta.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss editei a pergunta.

Comment: @IcaroMartins isso não funciona pq o elemento que quero adicionar a classe não existe no DOM.

Comment: Agora esta me parecendo que você esta procurando é uma forma de alterar o CSSRule `document.styleSheets`. talvez um desses links te ajude. [CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) , [pt.stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/282981/3774) ,  [en.sackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990089/dynamically-change-css-rules-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: Você adiciona os dados por ajax e quer esconder o botão depois que o ajax carregar, certo?